# What are the lightweight/ heavyweight components in WinForms?

Tags: java, c#, winforms, swing, awt

I know there are `lightweight` components and `heavyweight` components in `AWT` and `SWING`. But what is the counterpart to those in C# .NET `WinForms`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AWT, light weight components are written in Java and directly drawn to the screen by Java but are not known to the OS, where as heavy weight components are provided by the OS.

In WinForms all components are provided by the OS or derived from `Control` which is provided by the OS. Therefore this distinction does not exist in WinForms.

However; you could, in theory, have your own drawing logic drawing your own light weight controls on a form. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22354467/880990. If you need to interact with these controls, you will need to create hit tests in order to see which one of them was clicked and create your own interaction logic.

Comment: I thought a heavyweight component is for ex. a JDialog and a lightweight is the Button.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769072/differences-between-components-and-lightweight-heavyweight.

Comment: Thank you very much this helps me :)